# No muestra mensaje completo al llamar a una funcion de un objeto

Tags: javascript, objeto, funcion

Tengo este objeto

```
let cuentaBancaria ={
    nombre: 'Julia',
    apellido: 'Romero', 
    cedula: 25038013, 
    __proto__:{
        activa: true, 
        deudas: 100, 
        fecha_expiracion: 2023, 
        saldo_disponible: 1000, 
        ultima_transaccion: '12/09/2019'
    }, 
    mostrarInfo: function(){
        return 'datos del beneficiario: ', this.nombre
    }
}
console.log(cuentaBancaria.mostrarInfo())
```

al llamar a la function mostrarInfo() deberia salir el mensaje, 'datos del beneficiario:' sin embargo no me sale
y por otro lado tambien esta viendo que si le agrego este codigo a la linea de la funcion mostrarInfo()

```
}, 
        mostrarInfo: function(){
            return 'datos del beneficiario: ', this.nombre, this.apellido, this.cedula 
        }
```

solo aparece el ultimo dato, que es la cedula. Si alguien pudiera ilustrarme para aplicar la manera correcta de imprimir el mensaje y las propiedades cuando se llame a la funcion por favor y gracias

Comment: no se, leo [aquí](https://javascript.info/prototype-methods) que `__proto__` esta obsoleta... miralo a ver si sera eso

Comment: @anonymuus_gp algo así es lo que te refieres? https://jsfiddle.net/sawv0du5/

Comment: no tiene nada que ver con proto, tiene que ver con la impresion de las funciones

Comment: sii, muchas gracias, era esoo @JosueVargas

Comment: Dale te dejo respuesta, saludos

Answer (score 2):

Tu detalles está en que no concatenas correctamente

> En JS concatenas con *+*

te dejo tu código modificado

```js
let cuentaBancaria ={
    nombre: 'Julia',
    apellido: 'Romero', 
    cedula: 25038013, 
    __proto__:{
        activa: true, 
        deudas: 100, 
        fecha_expiracion: 2023, 
        saldo_disponible: 1000, 
        ultima_transaccion: '12/09/2019'
    }, 
    mostrarInfo: function(){
        return 'datos del beneficiario: '+this.nombre+" "+this.apellido+" "+this.cedula;
    }
}
console.log(cuentaBancaria.mostrarInfo())
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de retornar el string concatenado con esos valores es mediante el 'back tick' que permite crear [plantillas literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), esto basicamente te permite crear un string concatenando valores dentro de ${expresión}

```js
let cuentaBancaria ={
    nombre: 'Julia',
    apellido: 'Romero', 
    cedula: 25038013, 
    __proto__:{
        activa: true, 
        deudas: 100, 
        fecha_expiracion: 2023, 
        saldo_disponible: 1000, 
        ultima_transaccion: '12/09/2019'
    }, 
    mostrarInfo: function(){
        return `datos del beneficiario: ${this.nombre} ${this.apellido} ${this.cedula}`
    }
}
console.log(cuentaBancaria.mostrarInfo())
```

A mi parecer queda mucho más prolijo y legible el código